# Vagrant/PuPHPet mod_alias in config file

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I am looking to add an alias in a few of the vhosts in a new vagrant deploy. I am seeing in the documentation that it should be supported but every attempt I have made to add it to the config.yaml file does not seem to work.

Any information that can point me in the proper direction is greatly appreciated.

Here is the documentation I am referring to:

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache#aliases

Here is what I am trying to inject into the vhost:

```
Alias /api "/var/www/api/"
<Directory "/var/www/api/">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to drop your config.yaml to their website.
Then go to https://puphpet.com/upload-config#webserver
Use either

```
Custom Directives (inside <Directory> block)
```

Or

```
Custom Directives (outside <Directory> block)
```

Just put inside yours

> Alias /api/ /var/www/api/

It would output in your config.yaml

```
custom_fragment: 'Alias /api/ /var/www/api/'
```

I guess you can use it manually also.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was unaware you could upload your own yaml file. This may help since I need to create two <Directory> blocks: one for the vhost and one for the alias. Once I have the time and energy to attempt this again I will report back.